# JSerialComm not reading or closing port on Mac

Tags: java, macos

I have a microcontroller that I want to receive and send data to, so I tried to use the UART port to see if this could even be a possibility. I wrote a quick program for my microcontroller that would show the char value (not the character itself but the ASCII code) on a LCD screen and when I pressed a button it would send a 76 back (The code for 'L' because that is all this project has given me). I then downloaded CoolTerm for my Mac (I am using Mac because that is what my school gave me and not by choice) and plugged in [this](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B008AGDTA4) USB to UART cable I had bought. Once I downloaded the drivers I started CoolTerm, chose my port, and selected my baud rate. I hit connect and started pressing keys. When I did I got the correct corresponding ASCII values on my LCD and when I pressed the button on my microcontroller I did receive an 'L' in my terminal. Everything worked perfectly. I then downloaded jserialcomm and made a small program to just see if I could read the values coming in from the microcontroller. When I started the program it would only read in one byte every now and then even when I pressed the button or held it down. The byte that it would read would just be 1. Then another problem happened. It seemed that the port did not properly close. After the program has terminated I tried running it again and it would get stuck on trying the open the port and would never execute any code after that. When I would go to terminate the program it says it "fails to terminate" and then it, what I assume to be, force quits the program. When I go back to CoolTerm to open the port up it gets stuck on connecting and freezes and I have to force quit that. To be clear I am using the cu.* as the FAQ states and not the tty.*

This is the Java code that I am using:

```
 //This is what I use to set up the the Port 
    //This gets all of the ports on the machine
    SerialPort[] q;
    q = SerialPort.getCommPorts();

    //This iterates through the ports and gives a description and the name of the port
    for(SerialPort a: q){
        System.out.println(a.getDescriptivePortName() + " : " + a.getSystemPortName());
    }

    //Allows user to select which port they want
    System.out.println("Which port do you want?");
    Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
    int portnumber = s.nextInt();
    s.close();

    //Creates a SerialPort object of the port the user selected and opens it
    SerialPort commPort = q[portnumber];
    System.out.println(commPort.getDescriptivePortName());

    if(commPort.openPort()){
        System.out.println("Port Opened");
    }else{
        System.out.println("Port Failed to Open");
    }

    commPort.setBaudRate(230400);


//This is the first method I tried
commPort.setComPortTimeouts(SerialPort.TIMEOUT_NONBLOCKING, 1000, 0);
    try{
        while(true){
            //Waits till there are bytes available 
            while(commPort.bytesAvailable() == 0){
                Thread.sleep(20);
            }

            //Creates a buffer to read the bytes
            byte[] readBuffer = new byte[commPort.bytesAvailable()];
            int numOfBytes = commPort.readBytes(readBuffer, readBuffer.length);
            //Prints out the number of bytes read and the bytes it read
            System.out.println("Read " + numOfBytes + " bytes. Message:");
            for(byte b: readBuffer){
                System.out.println("::::" + Integer.toBinaryString(b & 0xFF));
            }

        }
    }catch(Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();

    }


The second method I did was using InputStreams which I would prefer not to use since I rather just read raw bytes in.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edit your timeout to:

```
commPort.setComPortTimeouts(SerialPort.TIMEOUT_NONBLOCKING, 0, 0);
```

or remove the line. In your case you do not need it. Why the weird baud rate? Sometimes the USB-to-RS232 bridges do not work with every baud rate.

Works for me with 9600baud.

Hope this helps,

Hani